# Sending data from Proteus to Ms.Excel sheet

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am unable to send serial output data to Ms.Excel sheet.
I am using Proteus 8 professional software, Arduino 1.8.5 IDE with windos 7 OS in a 32bit system. Could anyone please guide me to send the data.

Here is my Ardunio code:

```
int incomingByte = 0;

unsigned long time;
unsigned long day = 86400000; // 86400000 milliseconds in a day
unsigned long hour = 3600000; // 3600000 milliseconds in an hour
unsigned long minute = 60000; // 60000 milliseconds in a minute
unsigned long second =  1000; // 1000 milliseconds in a second
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}
void loop() {

if (Serial.available() > 0) 
{
incomingByte = Serial.read(); // read the incoming byte:

Serial.print("Time: ");
time = millis();
int days = time / day ;                                //number of days
int hours = (time % day) / hour;                       //the remainder from 
days division (in milliseconds) divided by hours, this gives the full hours
int minutes = ((time % day) % hour) / minute ;         //and so on...
int seconds = (((time % day) % hour) % minute) / second;

Serial.print(days,DEC);  
Serial.println(hours);  
Serial.println(minutes);
Serial.println(seconds);  

delay(1000);   
  }

}
```

Comment: Where does this code use any Excel features? What happens instead?

Comment: This is our code and we want its output to be stored in an excel sheet.

Comment: Could you suggest the way to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to write an Excel sheet? Thats complicated code. Why not use a CSV file?